# Job Status Dashboard in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there any ability to see job statuses in *Google Cloud Dataflow* beside checking them one-by-one? I mean something like a dashboard, with e.g. Job Status, ETA of completion, current resources used, errors (if any), etc.

Also, any plans to release a command line tool similar to `gsutil` and `bq`?

Thanks!

Comment: As a start, even the simple status of whether the job is currently running or not, will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out.  The current views that are available on the cloud console for Dataflow are the general job listing page (name + ID) and the job-specific details page.  We'd like to continue to improve this experience, though -- are there any other metrics besides deadline, resource consumption, and latest error that would be useful on a summary page?

To your second question, we are actively working on integrating Dataflow with the gcloud tool, but don't have anything to announce quite yet.

Cheers,
Sam